# ¿cuando uno maneja apuntadores la informacion se duplica?

Tags: c++, punteros

Cuando uno maneja apuntadores, ¿la informacion se duplica o hay alguna forma de crear algo asi como hipervinculos?

por ejemplo:

```
struct Ciudad{   

    //datos ciudad  

}

struct persona{

    Ciudad ciudadOrigen;  
    //otros datos
};
```

¿Cómo se podría hacer para pasar una referencia de la ciudad y no una copia de la ciudad (de tal forma que si hay 20 personas con la misma ciudad no hallan 20 ciudades en memoria)? ¿En este caso se usaría `'*'` o `'&'` o alguno otro?

Comment: cualquiera de ellos, puedes usar el puntero o la referencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cuando uno maneja apuntadores, ¿la informacion se duplica o hay alguna forma de crear algo asi como hipervinculos?

Si tu tienes dos variables *normales* queda claro, como se puede ver en el siguiente ejemplo, que la información se duplica:

```
int a = 10;
int b = a;
std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
a = 20;
std::cout << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
```

Si los punteros hiciesen esto mismo... ¿Cual sería la razón de su existencia?. Un puntero es una variable *normal* que, en vez de almacenar un resultado o un valor numérico, hace lo propio con direcciones de memoria. Si dos punteros apuntan a la misma región de memoria, entonces ambos accederán a la misma información. Es decir, la información no se va a duplicar ni nada por el estilo... la información está en una región de memoria determinada y son los punteros los que almacenan la posición de dicha información para poder acceder a ella.

Un equivalente en el *mundo real* son los números de teléfono. Cuando compartes tu número de móvil con tus amigos no les estás dando físicamente tu móvil (ellos no pueden hacer llamadas en tu lugar ni leer tus mensajes). El número de móvil sirve única y exclusivamente para localizarte y todos tus amigos pueden tener una *copia* de tu número de móvil.

> ¿Cómo se podría hacer para pasar una referencia de la ciudad y no una copia de la ciudad?

En C++ existen dos conceptos que son similares aunque no iguales:

- Punteros
- Referencias

Al igual que pasa con los punteros, las referencias son unas variables que almacenan una posición de memoria (como su nombre indica, sirven para referenciar a otras variables). Sin embargo, y a diferencia de los punteros, las referencias presentan una serie de restricciones, lo que hace que las mismas no puedan ser consideradas como punteros

- Las referencias se deben inicializar en la construcción

  ```
  int a = 5;
  int & ref1; // Error, referencia no inicializada
  int & ref2 = a; // ok
  std::cout << a << ref2 << '\n';
  a = 6
  std::cout << a << ref2 << '\n';
  ```
- Las referencias no pueden reasignarse

  ```
  int a = 5, b = 7;
  int & ref = a;
  ref = b; // Esto es equivalente a 'a = b'
  std::cout << a << b << ref << '\n';
  ref = &b; // Error, ref no es un puntero
  ```

Claro que también, gracias a estas restricciones, posee una serie de ventajas:

- Las referencias se usan como variables normales, por lo que el código se presenta de forma más natural y amigable:

  ```
  int a = 0;
  int & ref = a;  // No hay que usar el operador &
  int * ptr = &a; // Con los punteros si

  ref = 5;
  std::cout << a << ref << *ptr << '\n'; // Tampoco hay que usar *
  ```
- En el caso de referencias a objetos, el acceso a las funciones y variables miembro se hace con el operador `.` en vez de con el operador `->`:

  std::string cad = "abcde";
  std::string & ref = cad;
  std::string * ptr = &cad;

  std::cout << ref.count() << ptr->count() << '\n';

Las referencias son adecuadas para aquellas situaciones en las que sabemos que estas restricciones no nos van a suponer un problema... por ejemplo, hasta hace unos años era habitual usas referencias para evitar la copia de las cadenas de texto:

```
void imprimieMensaje(std::string const& mensaje)
{
  std::cout << mensaje;
}
```

Con todo esto, y contestando finalmente a tu pregunta, para hacer una copia de la ciudad bastaría con usar variables *normales*:

```
struct persona{
  Ciudad ciudadOrigen;  
};
```

Mientras que para usar referencias, lo más habitual es usar punteros:

```
struct persona{
  Ciudad* ciudadOrigen;  
};
```

Nota que también podrías llegar a usar referencias... pero entonces te encontrarías con las restricciones antes comentadas y eso tiene su impacto:

- Tendrías que conocer la ciudad antes de crear objetos de tipo `persona`.
- Una vez asignada la ciudad, no podrías cambiarla. Tendrías que borrar el objeto de tipo `persona` y crear uno nuevo con la nueva ciudad.

Comment: Podría clarificar lo de "hasta hace unos años era habitual usar referencias...". Qué es lo habitual ahora?

Comment: @Xam hoy en día hay un montón de optimizaciones y de objetos que hacen que no sea necesario usar referencias. Por ejemplo *copy elision* o *reference_wrapper*, punteros inteligentes, sintaxis *move*... hay muchas alternativas que se adaptan a muchísimas situaciones que antes solo se podían abordar con referencias y punteros

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!!... respondió a mi pregunta de manera clara